# Magento Community 1.9.1 Home Page Widgets are not working

Tags: rwd, widget

I'm trying to add widgets to my home page `new product` and `recently viewed`. I'm seeing allot of white space below the products price and decided look in to the css but there was no refrence, turns out the white space is added as in-line CSS (don't know from where its being generated) and upon editing the file `(frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml)` I noticed that "add to cart" (among other things) was supposed to be in that white space (one could presume). as a test I switched the home page's theme to "base" and I was able to see "add to cart" "add to wishlist" AND "add to compare" (in an ugly single list view). So apparently, Like '[lrkwz](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3515/lrkwz)reported, Widgets (at least a few) don't work right on the home page. Please advise!

http://kaleidoscopiacoloringbooks.com/Store/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the CSS defined in the madisoniland.css line 182.

Change line 182:

```
.cms-index-index .products-grid .ratings, .cms-index-index .products-grid .actions, .cms-index-noroute .products-grid .ratings, .cms-index-noroute .products-grid .actions {
display: none;
}
```

by removing or commenting out the:

```
display: none;
```

Doing this will correct your issue.

Comment: YES! thank you! how did you find this?! I couldn't find it using the Developer Tools in Chrome

Comment: Black magic! :) Actually I used FireFox's FireBug add-on to view the css of the offending element. I saw that the elements (add to cart etc) were present in the code but merely hidden so I stepped back through the element styles until I saw where they were being hidden. Hope this helps.